# Method to save child objects

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm using Entity Framework 6 with database first. See the image for the relevant database schema[image]

I have the following method to save a `Set` to the database:

```
/// <summary>
/// Saves the list of data sources. This assumes that the ModelTemplateID, SetNumber and TaskNumber
/// are already properly set. Adds a new record to the DataSourceGroups table if necessary.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="dataSources">The list of data sources to save</param>
public void SaveSet(IEnumerable<DataSource> dataSources)
{
    using (var db = _contextFactory.GetContext())
    {
        foreach (var dataSource in dataSources)
        {
            var dataSourceFromDb =
                db.DataSources.FirstOrDefault(x => x.DataSourceID == dataSource.DataSourceID);

            if (dataSourceFromDb == null)
            { // not in database yet, add it
                var dataSourceGroupFromDb =
                    db.DataSourceGroups.SingleOrDefault(
                        x => x.ModelTemplateID == dataSource.ModelTemplateID &&
                             x.SetNumber == dataSource.SetNumber &&
                             x.TaskNumber == dataSource.TaskNumber);
                if (dataSourceGroupFromDb == null)
                { // Add new DataSourceGroup to db
                    db.DataSourceGroups.Add(new DataSourceGroup
                    {
                        ModelTemplateID = dataSource.ModelTemplateID,
                        SetNumber = dataSource.SetNumber,
                        TaskNumber = dataSource.TaskNumber
                    });
                }
                db.DataSources.Add(dataSource);
            }
            else
            { // already in database, if any fields are different then update it
                if (dataSourceFromDb.QueryID      != dataSource.QueryID || // todo make DataSource Comparer
                    dataSourceFromDb.SourceType   != dataSource.SourceType ||
                    dataSourceFromDb.TargetFormat != dataSource.TargetFormat ||
                    dataSourceFromDb.SourcePath   != dataSource.SourcePath ||
                    dataSourceFromDb.TargetPath   != dataSource.TargetPath)
                {
                    db.DataSources.Attach(dataSource);
                    db.Entry(dataSource).State = EntityState.Modified;
                }
            }
        }
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Is this the best way to implement this method? Should I be attaching the `DataSources` to the `Set` when they are created and then just pass the `Set` into the method? Any other critiques welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> /// <summary>
> /// Saves the list of data sources. This assumes that the ModelTemplateID, SetNumber and TaskNumber
> /// are already properly set. Adds a new record to the DataSourceGroups table if necessary.
> /// </summary>
> /// <param name="dataSources">The list of data sources to save</param>
> public void SaveSet(IEnumerable<DataSource> dataSources)
> ```

The method name is telling a lie. `SaveSet` would be appropriate if the method took an `IEnumerable<Set> sets` parameter. I would have called the method `SaveDataSources`.

Per the XML comments, the method is making assumptions, but it does nothing to verify these assumptions, and since the method has no return type, the only way you can fail is by letting it throw - throwing is good in this situation, however it's best to *fail early*, if possible *before* you even create the context instance.

This is done with a *guard clause* at the top of your method, that aborts the call if an argument is invalid - for example:

```
if (dataSources.Any(dataSource => 
       dataSource.ModelTemplateID == default(typeof(dataSource.ModelTemplateID))
    || dataSource.SetNumber == default(typeof(dataSource.ModelTemplateID))
    || dataSource.TaskNumber == default(typeof(dataSource.TaskNumber))))
{
    throw new ArgumentException("Members 'ModelTemplateID', 'SetNumber' and 'TaskNumber' not set.", "dataSources");
}
```

This makes your code throw a more meaningful exception, instead of adding half the items, throwing some foreign key exception and then disposing the context without persisting anything.

---

> ```
> using (var db = _contextFactory.GetContext())
> ```

While a conveniently short identifier, `db` is a misleading name to use for a `DbContext`; it's more of a *context* than a *database*, so `context` would be more appropriate.

I like that the method isn't directly responsible for creating the `DbContext` instance, however `GetContext()` sounds like you're not *creating* anything, rather just returning an existing instance - which is counter-intuitive in the context (pun not intended) of a factory. `CreateContext` would be better, and since `_contextFactory` is already a quite descriptive name, a `Create` method wouldn't be any less clear:

```
using (var context = _contextFactory.Create())
{
```

---

> ```
> foreach (var dataSource in dataSources)
> {
>     var dataSourceFromDb =
>         db.DataSources.FirstOrDefault(x => x.DataSourceID == dataSource.DataSourceID);
> ```

Unless I look at your schema and see that `DataSourceID` is the entity's *primary key*, I have no way of being sure that you're expecting only a single record, because `FirstOrDefault` could just as well operate on 20 entities and only return the first that matches the criteria.

This would be less ambiguous, because if more than 1 entity is returned, `SingleOrDefault` would throw an exception:

```
foreach (var dataSource in dataSources)
{
    var dataSourceFromDb = 
            context.DataSources
                   .SingleOrDefault(e => e.DataSourceID == dataSource.DataSourceID);
```

---

This part looks like it belongs in another method:

> ```
>         if (dataSourceFromDb == null)
>         { // not in database yet, add it
>             var dataSourceGroupFromDb =
>                 db.DataSourceGroups.SingleOrDefault(
>                     x => x.ModelTemplateID == dataSource.ModelTemplateID &&
>                          x.SetNumber == dataSource.SetNumber &&
>                          x.TaskNumber == dataSource.TaskNumber);
>             if (dataSourceGroupFromDb == null)
>             { // Add new DataSourceGroup to db
>                 db.DataSourceGroups.Add(new DataSourceGroup
>                 {
>                     ModelTemplateID = dataSource.ModelTemplateID,
>                     SetNumber = dataSource.SetNumber,
>                     TaskNumber = dataSource.TaskNumber
>                 });
>             }
>             db.DataSources.Add(dataSource);
> ```

I don't like the comments on the same line as the scope-opening brace `{ //`, and these comments wouldn't be needed at all if you extracted the method; the added level of abstraction would speak for itself:

```
if (dataSourceFromDb == null)
{
    EnsureDataSourceGroupExists(context, dataSource);
    context.DataSources.Add(dataSource)
}
else
{
    dataSourceFromDb.QueryID = dataSource.QueryID;
    dataSourceFromDb.SourceType = dataSource.SourceType;
    dataSourceFromDb.TargetFormat = dataSource.TargetFormat;
    dataSourceFromDb.SourcePath = dataSource.SourcePath;
    dataSourceFromDb.TargetPath = dataSource.TargetPath;
}

context.SaveChanges();
```

Notice the how the *update* code is simply copying the values from `dataSource` into the members of `dataSourceFromDb` - that entity is already *attached* and managed by the change tracker. Why complicate things? It's there, might as well use it!

One thing your code also assumes, is that `SaveChanges` will insert the `DataSourceGroup` entity *before* it inserts `dataSource`. I don't know about EF6, but in other versions one cannot make that assumption, so `EnsureDataSourceGroupExists` would call `SaveChanges` on the context if a new entity was created. Not doing this is like asking for a foreign key violation.

Comment: We'll have to agree to disagree on the name of the method; in our domain a Set is a list of DataSources. Based on code elsewhere in the application, I don't think that I need to check that the ModelTemplateID, SetNumber and TaskNumber are not set, they are guaranteed to be set when the objects are created. Good suggestion on changing the name of GetContext() to Create(); it is returning a new instance each time. Also a good suggestion on changing FirstOrDefault() to SingleOrDefault().

Comment: I also agree that the method should be split up some more. Good suggestion on just copying the properties, that's due to my ignorance of EF. I haven't run into any FK issues yet, but I'll be sure to call SaveChanges when inserting a DataSourceGroup to make sure. Thanks a lot.